# HERE map：Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/AssertionError;.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V"

Tags: java, android, maps, here-api

```
11-21 17:26:54.852 9831-9864/? E/NETWORK: [ERROR] NETWORK - Request: https://places.hybrid.api.here.com/places/v1/meta/offline?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE Error: 400 Bad Request
11-21 17:26:58.097 9831-9915/? E/art: No <init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V in java.lang.Class<java.lang.AssertionError>    
11-21 17:26:58.103 9831-9915/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3                                       
Process: com.zfz.fhl.heremap, PID: 9831                                                 
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()                                                     
  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)                                                
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)                                                     
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)                                                  
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)                                                   
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)    
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)                                                         
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Ljava/lang/AssertionError;.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V"                                                    
  at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest.poll(Native Method)                                              
  at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest.e(PlacesBaseRequest.java:62)                                                     
  at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest$b.a(PlacesBaseRequest.java:732)                                                     
  at com.nokia.maps.PlacesBaseRequest$b.doInBackground(PlacesBaseRequest.java:713)                                                     
  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)                                                     
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)                                                     
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)                                                    
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)                                                     
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is my main code:

```
GeoCoordinate geoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773);

 DiscoveryRequest request = new SearchRequest("restaurant").setSearchCenter(geoCoordinate);

                    ErrorCode execute = request.execute(new ResultListener<DiscoveryResultPage>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(DiscoveryResultPage discoveryResultPage, ErrorCode errorCode) {
                            if (discoveryResultPage != null) {
                                List<DiscoveryResult> discoveryResultList = discoveryResultPage.getItems();
                                for (DiscoveryResult result :
                                        discoveryResultList) {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

app_id and app_code are correct,this is a very simple demo,other code is to load the map,after add these above codes and then this error appeared,and I think this error is caused by HERE MAP SDK,if anyone ever met and can solve this question,please reply In the following,thank you for you spend time to answer

Comment: _400 Bad Request_ . Something is wrong with your request.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer,I noticed 400 Bad Request before,and It is possible caused by 400 Bad Request,but I can access this URL in a browser,so I am not sure where the problem lies,do you have any ideas about this or solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not actually sure. Make sure your manifest meets the requirements specified.

Answer (score 0):

I really no way for a long time,I changed a piece of android equipment,and appeared other error:
E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.gson.GsonBuilder', referenced from method com.nokia.maps.dz.
and then I imported the gson package,the problem is solved,I think this is very strange,different android equipment appeared different error,these two error are very different